# Access nested movieclips in flash file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an application created in Flash Builder 4 that loads SWFs of flash files and I want to access movie clips within these flash files.  I can access top level movie clips using:

```
var assetName:String = "example_mc";
this._graphics[assetName].addChild(this._customText);
```

However when I want to access nested movie clips I am unsuccessful, I have tried:

```
var assetName:String = "example_mc";
var assetName2:String = "example2_mc";
this._graphics[assetName][assetName2].addChild(this._customText);
```

and I have tried:

```
MovieClip(DisplayObjectContainer(this._graphics.getChildByName(assetName)).getChildByName(assetName2)).addChild(this._customText);
```

In addition I tried variants of the square brackets and "getChildByName" but still no success.

All moviclips are instantiated in frame 1 of the Flash files, any ideas?

- Edit ** 
  I forgot to tweak my error handling so an error would be shown, plus all my tests where not showing text, late afternoon on a Mon is not my brightest hour! ;)  I worked it out in the end, the solution was either (as above):

  ```
  MovieClip(DisplayObjectContainer(this._graphics.getChildByName(assetName)).getChildByName(assetName2)).addChild(this._customText);
  ```

Or:

```
    MovieClip(DisplayObjectContainer(this._graphics.getChildByName(assetName))[assetName2]).addChild(this._customText);
```

Hopefully this can help someone else out.

Thanks

Chris

Comment: Please post the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your flash file is loaded AND initialized before trying to access child movie clips by listening to the Event.COMPLETE or Event.INIT event.

Example:
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onComplete);

You can also reference everything easier by just typing
    this._graphics.example_mc.example2_mc.addChild(this._customText);